# C# One To Many Relationship

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL

```
SELECT p.Price, p.ID, p.Name, c.Name as CategoryName, p.CategoryID, c.ID AS CategoryPK,c.ParentID
,o.ID as OrderID,o.ProductID,o.ClientCompanyID,o.Quentity
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryID=c.ID LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.ProductID=p.ID
```

And this code

```
static List<Product> GetProducts(SqlCommand command)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));

        product.Name = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")) ? (string)reader["Name"] : null);

        product.Price = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("Price"));
        product.CategoryID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CategoryID"));
        Category newCat = new Category();
        newCat.ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CategoryPK"));
        newCat.CategoryName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CategoryName"));
        newCat.Parent = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ParentID")) ? reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ParentID")) : 0);
        product.Category = newCat;

        Order order = new Order();
        order.ID = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderID")) ? (int?)reader["OrderID"] : null);
        order.ClientCompanyID = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ClientCompanyID")) ? (int?)reader["ClientCompanyID"] : null);
        order.ProductID = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductID")) ? (int?)reader["ProductID"] : null);
        order.Quentity = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Quentity")) ? (int?)reader["Quentity"] : null);

        List<Order> listOrders = new List<Order>();
        listOrders.Add(order);

        product.Orders = listOrders;
        listProducts.Add(product);
    }
    reader.Close();
    return listProducts;
}
```

**Question** is: How to remove duplicates without losing any orders when I call orders from a single product like this:

```
{
    foreach (var item in listProducts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product Name : {0} Price : {1} Category : {2}", item.Name, item.Price, item.Category.CategoryName, item);

        foreach (var orders in item.Orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Order : " + orders.Quentity + " Price : " + (float)item.Price * orders.Quentity);
        }
    }
}
```

I want when I call `product.order.id` to show all orders from this product.
One to many relation how i should make it ?

Products |Orders

Product A|######X

### .#########|######Y

Product B|######Z

###|######K

I mean Product A can have much orders and same for product B.
One to many how to impliment this.

Comment: Please clarify "how to make when i call orders from single product to remove dublicates without lose any orders like this"

Comment: Sorry i want this. I want to show all products and all orders from this product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your C# object you just need to check if the Product already exists.
Something like this:

```
static List<Product> GetProducts(SqlCommand command)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int productId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
        Product product = null;
        //check if product exists
        foreach (Product p in listProducts)
        {
           if(p.ID = productId)
               product = p;//product already exists
        }

       if(product == null)
       {
          //product doesn't exist, create new
          product = new Product();
          product.ID = productId;

          product.Name = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")) ? (string)reader["Name"] : null);

          product.Price = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("Price"));
          product.CategoryID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CategoryID"));
          Category newCat = new Category();
          newCat.ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CategoryPK"));
          newCat.CategoryName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CategoryName"));
          newCat.Parent = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ParentID")) ? reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ParentID")) : 0);
          product.Category = newCat;
          product.Orders = new List<Order>();
        }

        //add order to product
        Order order = new Order();
        order.ID = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("OrderID")) ? (int?)reader["OrderID"] : null);
        order.ClientCompanyID = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ClientCompanyID")) ? (int?)reader["ClientCompanyID"] : null);
        order.ProductID = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductID")) ? (int?)reader["ProductID"] : null);
        order.Quentity = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Quentity")) ? (int?)reader["Quentity"] : null);
        product.Orders.Add(order);
        listProducts.Add(product);
    }
    reader.Close();
    return listProducts;
}
```

You could make this faster if your SQL result was ordered by product, then instead of checking if the current product already exists, you could simply check if it is different from the last one. (If it is different make a new product if it is not different just add the order to the last product.)

Comment: Yes i've made some changes.